# how to store the values to a variable

Tags: bash, lftp

I'm try to get the used storage for a ftp server through lftp.

```
lftp :~> open username:password@IP
lftp username@IP:~> du
897146  ./volume(sda1)
897146  .
```

I want to get the value of `897146` from a sh script.

This is what I got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

FTP_PASS=password
FTP_HOST=IP
FTP_USER=username
LFTP=lftp


lftp  << EOF
open ${FTP_USER}:${FTP_PASS}@${FTP_HOST}
FOO="$(du)"
quit
EOF
echo "$FOO"
```

But I'm getting

```
Unknown command `FOO=9544       ./logs'.
Unknown command `9636'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `du` command inside the FTP session will output within the `lftp` command output. So to get the output of the `du` command, you need to capture the output of the `lftp` command inside your variable:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
FTP_PASS=password
FTP_HOST=IP
FTP_USER=username


FOO=$(lftp  << EOF | filter_out_things_unrelated_to_du
open ${FTP_USER}:${FTP_PASS}@${FTP_HOST}
du
quit
EOF
)
echo "$FOO"
```

You will probably need to filter-out the FTP session header and MOTD from the remote FTP server and anything not related with the output of `du`.